# Set attributes of a figure with subplots

Tags: python, figure, subplot

I am new in plotting with python. I have made a plot with 4 subplots. Knowing the attributes `dpi` and `figsize`, how can I set them for my fig?

```
myfig,xarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
```

I know this command exists:

```
plt.figure(dpi=100,figsize=(5,5))
```

but not sure how to attach it to `myfig`.

Comment: both commands are somewhat redundant. The first one is sufficient to do what you want. You can pass the optional keyword argumends `dpi` and `figsize` into the subplots function.

Comment: yesss! It works! I didn't know that!
thank you @dnalow. If you post it as an answer, I'd accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both commands are somewhat redundant. The first one is sufficient to do what you want. You can pass the optional keyword argumends `dpi` and `figsize` into it.